# Repeat music in Chromecast

Tags: youtube, music, chromecast

Found [this song](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=TpELMk4-3n8&feature=share) and want to play it in a loop through the TV when using Chromecast.

When I'm using YouTube Music before Chromecast, then I'm able to repeat it. Thing is, once I start to Chromecast it, then the button to repeat gets faded

[image]

This is a problem because the sound is not as powerful as when on the TV.

Comment: [This says YouTube loop isn't allowed but with Google Play Music it works](https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/thread/10778450/how-can-we-repeat-a-song-that-we-are-playing-on-a-chromecast-the-repeat-button-disappears?hl=en) //Not tested by me

Comment: @beeshyams Google Play Music is no longer available. It became YouTube Music

Comment: In that case maybe some other app can do that.. Not sure

Comment: @beeshyams just noticed now even YouTube doesn't allow to Chromecast a big playlist that one wants unless it's selected one by one. Making a move for people to use YouTube Music for that purpose instead yet not giving the full functionality even for Pro users

Comment: Maybe open an issue in Google support forum? Not that they are likely to act but you never know